# Where is the best place to invoke `removeObserver:name:object:`

Tags: objective-c, observer-pattern, dealloc

Where is the best place to invoke `removeObserver:name:object:` since the `dealloc` method does not always be executed as mentioned in NSObject class reference ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to [this note](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/dealloc):

> **Important:** Note that when an application terminates, objects may not be sent a `dealloc` message since the process’s memory is automatically cleared on exit—it is more efficient simply to allow the operating system to clean up resources than to invoke all the memory management methods.

It says `dealloc` is typically not guaranteed to be called only on application termination. So even if `dealloc` isn't called, the resources used by your application will still be cleared by the OS. That means all your objects will be gone anyway because your application isn't there anymore.

Therefore, the best place to remove a notification observer from the notification center is still within the observer's `dealloc` method.

Comment: Yeah I am referring to that note! I assumed that the observer will still exist despite the fact that the objects are destroyed. But I was probably wrong! Thank you.